# Read file as a list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy, text

Most pythonic way to import a raw string from a txt file into a list? contents of "file.txt" looks like this (all in a single line):

```
["string1","anotha one","more text","foo","2the","bar","fin"]
```

I could easily copy/paste the string into my script but am sure there is a more dynamic method.

In basic pseudocode:

```
my_list = *contents of file.txt*
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read it as json

```
import json
with open('file.txt', 'r') as list_file:
    my_list = json.load(list_file)

print (my_list)
```

#### Output should be

`['string1', 'anotha one', 'more text', 'foo', '2the', 'bar', 'fin']`

Comment: I think this is probably the cleanest solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From the [Python input-output tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html):

> To read a file’s contents, call `f.read(size)`, which reads some quantity of data and returns it as a string. `size` is an optional numeric argument. When `size` is omitted or negative, the entire contents of the file will be read and returned; it’s your problem if the file is twice as large as your machine’s memory. Otherwise, at most `size` bytes are read and returned. If the end of the file has been reached, `f.read()` will return an empty string (`""`).

```
>>> f.read()
'This is the entire file.\n'
>>> f.read()
''
```

Comment: This method returns the text, but wrapped in single quotes. I am hoping there is a way to essentially read the text in as if it were a direct input into the code

Comment: You are true. But I'm not sure which list do you want. Lines? Words? If it is lines, you could use list = file.readlines() or, better, list = file.read().split('\n')

Answer (score 0):

I got this in a couple of lines:

```
# Read your single line into the workspace.
with open(fname) as f:
    content = f.readline()
# Process the line to get your list of strings.
processed = [s.strip('[]"') for s in content[0].split(sep=',')]
# processed = ['string1', 'anotha one', 'more text', 'foo', '2the', 'bar', 'fin']
```

Breaking that second part down:

- `content[0].split(sep=',')` gives `['["string1"', '"anotha one"', '"more text"', '"foo"', '"2the"', '"bar"', '"fin"]']`, so it splits your input into a list at each comma character, but leaves some ugly extra characters in place from your raw input string
- `s.strip('[]"')` will remove any instances of bracket characters or the double quotes character `"` from the string `s`
- `[s.strip(...) for s in stuff]` applies the strip to every string in the newly separated list

If you have multiple lines in your file:

```
# Read your file into the workspace.
with open(fname) as f:
    content = f.readlines()
# Process each line to get your list of strings.
processed = []
for line in content:
    processed.append([s.strip('[]"\n ') for s in line.split(sep=',')])
```

Note I had to add the newline character and a white space character to the characters to be stripped to fully clean the multi-line case.

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
import re

with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f:

    print [i for i in  re.sub('\s+',' ',f.read()).strip().split(" ")]
```